# Colorblind mode for reviewing suggested edits

Tags: feature-request, design, suggested-edits, accessibility, colorblind

Roughly 8% of men and 0.5% of women are colorblind, the vast majority of which fall into the red-green category, including myself. When reviewing suggested edits, the colors used to differentiate what's being removed, and what's being added are in red and green. This is, unsurprisingly, a deterrent to performing this necessary activity for colorblind users. More widely usable default values should be selected, or an option to select an alternative palette (though this is more complicated to implement).

I am aware there are browser extension which can modify the appearance of sites, however the prevalence of this condition suggests these default values are failing a large number of users unnecessarily.

Comment: I imagine this would apply to anywhere that shows a diff (e.g. revision history, reopen queue), not just suggested edits?

Comment: Just out of curiosity, is dark mode any better? I think this should be implemented eventually, but I 'm just wondering if it would be a suitable workaround in the mean time.

Comment: I'd support a separate palette aimed at colorblind users rather than changing  the default template. Without having any idea what I'm talking about, I'm assuming there's additional types of color-blindness that might have the exact opposite of a benefit from something that would help red-green colorblind people. A palette-based system, while possibly harder to implement, would cover as many of the categories as possible, and allow for additional types to help with accessibility.

Comment: @Chipster Darkmode diffs are essentially unusable

Comment: @Nick...Totally agree...unusable

Comment: Couldn't agree more. I'm not even fully red-green colourblind, but I rarely approve any suggested edits that make changes to several places of a title as I can never follow what's going on. The number of very low contrast elements that have crept into recent revisions to the site's appearance make some things even worse, too. A colour-blind mode woul be lovely. I use dark mode in my IDE, etc., but I had to turn it off after about 5 mins on SO as it was basically unusable for me.

Comment: There are ways to show differences that use color and, say, shape or shadow to show changes. So you could keep the red and green, but also include something like text-shadow on the inserts. It might feel a bit "busy" to non-colorblind people, but personally I'm okay with a little "fugliness" in my UI for the sake of including an extra 0.5-8% of the potential audience...

Comment: Increasing contrast would help. The WACG has contrast guidelines for [text](https://www.w3.org/WAI/WCAG21/Understanding/contrast-minimum.html) and for [UI elements/graphics](https://www.w3.org/WAI/WCAG21/Understanding/non-text-contrast).